# Shooting method singular matrix warnings

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to implement the shooting method in python and am encountering error messages for singular matrices. I want to solve `xy''' = -y'y+x^2-1` with boundary conditions `y(1)=1, y(2)=1, y'(2)=4`. I transformed this into first order equations M(x,**y**) **y**' = f(x,**y**), with:

```
M = [1  0  0]
    [0  1  0]
    [0  0  x]

**y** = [ y ]
        [ y']
        [y''] 
f = [     y'   ]
    [     y''  ]
    [-y'y+x^2-1]
```

I've implemented the shooting method as described in Numerical Recipes 18.1. The general procedure is:

1. Specify boundary conditions on both the left and right sides. In my case, this is y(1)=1, y(2)=1, y'(2)=4. Provide as initial guess for the (y, y', y'') vector. I chose (1, 1, 2). The first element is fixed, as y(1)=1, but the other two elements make up the freely specifiable vector **V** containing the other boundary conditions on the LHS.
2. Integrate the equations x=1 to x=2. Define a discrepancy vector **F** calculated as the difference between the prescribed boundary conditions (y(2)=1 and y'(2)=4) and the values calculated through the integration.
3. Use Newton-Raphson to find a **V** that zeros **F**. Accomplish this by solving **J**.δ**V**=**-F** and adding the correction back to **V**. **J** is the Jacobian, found numerically at each time step.

If I assume that M is invertible, then this is relatively straightforward to solve and works as expected. However, I'm encountering two problems and would appreciate some assistance on how to solve them.

1. If I set the xrange from -1 to 1, I get a singular matrix warning. I think this is because I assumed M is invertible, but it isn't when x=0. The same problem arises frequently if M has any dependence on **y** This looks like a differential algebraic equation. Are there any convenient ways to solve this in python? It doesn't look like there are any built into scipy.
2. If I change my boundary condition at x=2 to be y(2)=-1, I also get a singular matrix warning. I'm not sure why this is happening. Is this maybe just an inability for the differential equations to satisfy the boundary conditions or something wrong with my code? If the former, is there any way to predict this ahead of time?

[A previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972693/matrix-is-singular-shooting-method) suggested that a better guess of initial conditions might help in the second singular case, but I'm not sure how to improve my guess without a lot of brute force.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

### Solving the differential equation xy''' = -y'y+x^2-1  
### if x range doesn't include 0, then M is invertible, so equations become:
def fn(y,x):
    return np.array([y[1],y[2],(-y[0]*y[1]+x**2-1)/x])

### Boundary values of y(1)=1, y(2)=1, y'(2)=4

x = np.linspace(1.,2.,101)
y0 = np.array([1., 1., 2.]) ### Only the first of these is fixed. The others are variable
sol = np.array([1.,4.]) ### Specify y(2)=1 y'(2)=4
Delta=1
max_itrs = 100

eps = 1e-3

def shoot(y0, Delta, fn, x, sol, eps, max_itrs):
    ### Throughtout this function, the indexing only works with our specific boundary conditions
    ### But can be easily modified or generalized to accommodate other cases
    for i in range(max_itrs):
        F = odeint(fn, y0, x)[-1][:2]-sol ### Define the F "discrepancy" vector at x = 2
        if np.linalg.norm(F)>eps:
            y0_yp_mod = y0.copy()
            y0_yp_mod[1] += Delta ### Augment y'(1) by Delta
            F_yp_mod = odeint(fn, y0_yp_mod, x)[-1][:2]-sol 

            y0_ypp_mod = y0.copy()
            y0_ypp_mod[2] += Delta ### Augment y''(1) by Delta
            F_ypp_mod = odeint(fn, y0_ypp_mod, x)[-1][:2]-sol

            ### Compute the Jacobian
            j11 = (F_yp_mod[0]-F[0])/Delta
            j12 = (F_yp_mod[1]-F[1])/Delta
            j21 = (F_ypp_mod[0]-F[0])/Delta
            j22 = (F_ypp_mod[1]-F[1])/Delta
            jac = np.array([[j11,j12],[j21,j22]])

            ### Solve for delta V:
            d_V = np.linalg.solve(jac,-F)

            ### Augment our initial conditions by delta V
            y0 = np.array([y0[0],y0[1]+d_V[0],y0[2]+d_V[1]])
        else:
            return y0
    print("Failed to achieve convergence after "+str(max_itrs)+" iterations.")
    return y0

y0 = shoot(y0, Delta, fn, x, sol, eps, max_itrs)
Y = odeint(fn, y0, x)
plt.plot(x,Y[:,0],c="r",label="y")
plt.plot(x,Y[:,1],c="g",label="y'")
plt.plot(x,Y[:,2],c="b",label="y''")
plt.scatter([x[0]],y0[0],marker="x",c="r")
plt.scatter([x[-1]],sol[0],marker="x",c="r")
plt.scatter([x[-1]],sol[1],marker="x",c="g")
plt.legend()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pPGt.png) is the output, which behaves as expected
[image: output]

Comment: Is the problem only the singular matrix warnings in the second case?

Comment: Both cases give me singular matrix warnings. I think I know where they're coming from in the first case, but don't know how to fix it in either of the two cases.

Comment: There's a couple of options I can think of: For one, you can try and avoid regions where matrices are singular by adjusting your initial guess.  (-1,-4,7) might be better than (1,1,2) or instance.  The other option would be to do some sort of change of variables to improve the conditioning of the matrix you're inverting.  Printing out the matrix when you get these warnings might give a hint of how to do that.  The last thing might be just to ignore the warnings.  They're there to tell you that your matrix is poorly conditioned but if your solution is good enough you might not care.